# How to effeciently draw multiple line shape in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, html5-canvas

I've been working on a hobby project, which is rebuilding the old DOS game Gotcha in HTML5. The part with drawing blocks has been done almost (aside from some nasty bugs), but the thing I'm struggling with now is to draw the spinner that the game has. I've uploaded a screenshot from the spinner with multiple deformations. http://www.mvdms.com/gotcha/spinner.png. My question is: How can I reproduce such an advanced animation in HTML5 with use of the canvas object?

I searched everywhere for similar animations, but I just can't find it. My current code for the spinner is pretty simple:

Initialization:

```
    APP.spinnerLines = new Array();

    for(i = 0; i< 12; i++)
    {
        var line = new Line(13,20);
        line.points.push(new Point(i*5,0));

        APP.spinnerLines.push(line);
    }
```

Updating: (every FPS)

```
        for(i in APP.spinnerLines)
        {                       
            var lpX;
            var lpY;

            for(j in APP.spinnerLines[i].points)
            {
                lpX = APP.spinnerLines[i].points[j].x;
                lpY = APP.spinnerLines[i].points[j].y;

                context.moveTo(lpX, lpY);
                if(APP.spinnerLines[i].points[parseInt(j)+1] !== undefined)
                {
                    lpX = APP.spinnerLines[i].points[parseInt(j)+1].x;
                    lpY = APP.spinnerLines[i].points[parseInt(j)+1].y;

                    context.lineTo(lpX, lpY);
                }
            }
        }
```

There is also a bit collision detection later on in the code, but that isn't relevant for the object for now I guess ;)

So, is there anybody who could help me out with drawing this shape in HTML5?

My current status of the project is viewable on http://www.mvdms.com/gotcha (move with the arrow keys)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You haven't posted a link to what the spinner is supposed to look like?

Comment: You were right, my excuses. I have edited the post with the link included.

Comment: Did you get it working? The current status link looks like you got parallel lines chasing around the rectangle?  I looked at your shape, but it was hard to make out details of what you want.

Comment: for/in looping with arrays is a profoundly bad idea: it walks over all object properties, not just the elements that have numerical keys. Using for/in without a safeguard means you'll also be accessing things like "length", "map", "forEach", and other Array() specific properties in addition to the indexed elements.